# Exactly how left join on clause is applied

Tags: sql

I'm a bit confused about how on clause is applied in left joins. As far as I know the on clause is similar to the where clause but is applied before the actual join rather than after it as the where clause does.

How ever, I'm trying to limit the amount of records in the left table of the join including a condition in the on clause, but I'm still getting all records from the left one.

An example follows:

```
Table A
a    b
-------
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400

Table B
z    y
-------
200 20000
300 30000
```

The query I'm doing is:

```
select *
from A a
    left join Z z
        on a.b = z.z
            and a.a in (1, 2, 3);
```

But in the result I'm still getting rows with a.a = 4, why?. Doing a where clause solves the problem, but I was hopping to get rid of those records as soon as possible ( in the real scenario query others joins follow ).

```
Result
------
1   100 NULL    NULL
2   200 200 20000
3   300 300 30000
4   400 NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL statements *describe* the result set.  They do not specify exactly how the result is calculated.

For a `left join`, the rules are to keep all the rows in the first table and then all matching rows in the second table.  This is true regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to true, false, or NULL.

So, if you do:

```
select *
from A a left join
     Z z
     on 1 = 0
```

Then you will get all rows in the `A` table, even though the `on` clause *always* evaluates to false.  The columns from `Z` will all be `NULL`.

If you do:

```
select *
from A a left join
     Z z
     on a.b = z.z and a.a in (1, 2, 3);
```

Then you will *still* get all rows in the first table.

The simple rule is that conditions on the *first* table go in the `where`, and conditions in the second (and subsequent) tables go on the `on`:

```
select *
from A a left join
     Z z
     on a.b = z.z 
where a.a in (1, 2, 3);
```

The rules are exactly the opposed for `right join`.  For an `inner` join it doesn't matter if they conditions go in the `on` or the `where`.  For a `full outer join` . . . well then you often find yourself using subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

It should be right join. Following query returns 2 rows

select *
from A a
    right join B z
        on a.b = z.z
            and a.a in (1, 2, 3);